# How to write to Azure Search Index from Synapse Spark?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-synapse

How to write to Azure Search Index from Synapse Spark?

Synapse has a Linked service connection to Azure Search but I am unable to find documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Azure search has a provider for Synapse but it does not follow the regular pattern.
Here is the code.

```
dataFrame \
.withColumn('searchAction', lit('upload')) \
.writeToAzureSearch(subscriptionKey=TokenLibrary.getSecret('your-key-vault','azure-search-key'),
                    actionCol="searchAction",
                    serviceName='your-search-service',
                    indexName='your-search-index',
                    batchSize='1000',
                    keyCol="id");
```

The magic column 'searchAction' tell Azure Search what do to like "upload", "delete", "merge", or "mergeOrUpload".
The keyCol is used to upsert or delete.